# Pandas Dataframe + Flask, request only one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask

I got the following problem. I want only one row from the pandas dataframe. 
I´ve some trouble by printing the one row as html. I used the .loc function to get the row from the dataframe. How can i return only one row in html...
Atm i got the keyerror...

Thanks for your help. That´s my code..
First I open a connection to my db and transform the data into a pandas dataframe. 
Than I only want to print one row. The row with the indexnumber that typed in the url.
Any ideas how the problem can be solved?

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


connection = sqlite3.connect("meinedb.db") 
df = pd.read_sql_query("select name, frequenz from popular_girlnames order by frequenz desc limit 10;", connection)
print(df.iloc[0 , 0])


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return "Hallo du bist der erste Besucher!!!!"


@app.route('/test=<num>', methods=["GET"])
def get_name(num):
    return df.loc[num, "name"].to_html(classes = "Name")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: did you try: `print(df.iloc[0])`

Comment: I use "return df.iloc[int(num) , 0]". Now i get the right answer from the server!